# Start an interactive bash login shell with modified $PATH

Tags: bash, macos

In a GUI application I'm developing, I need to open an interactive terminal pane in which the PATH is set so that the correct versions of helper tools are found first.

On some environments, especially on Mac, terminal windows are spawned as login shells, because the parent UI process has not evaluated the usual init files like `/etc/profile` or `$HOME/.bash_profile`.

Because of that, many people have set up their aliases, helper-sourcings / evals (rbenv, rvm, ..) etc in a way that they are only loaded for login shells.

For this reason, I would like the terminal tab to open a login shell instead of a non-login one, but I haven't found a way to modify the PATH after all of the default scripts are evaluated.

Looks like `bash --login --init-file <(echo "echo hello")` never evaluates the init file (supplied via an anonymous pipe).

Is there a way to start a login shell with a PATH that is set after all the startup scripts have been loaded?

I have this working for Fish and Zsh, which will be the new default shell on MacOS Catalina, but can't figure out how to make it work on bash.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, `--login`/`-l` seems to disable `--init-file`.

What about executing an **interactive** shell and passing it **profile** and **interactive** script:

```
bash --init-file <(echo 'for p in /etc/profile ~/.bash_profile .bashrc; do
                           if [[ -f "$p" ]] ; then source "$p"; fi
                         done')
```

Comment: I think only the first hit of `~/.bash_profile`, `~/.bash_login` and `~/.profile` is sourced. `~/.bashrc` is never sourced for non login shells`, at least according to the "initialization file decision tree" in https://medium.com/@youngstone89/unix-introduction-bash-startup-files-loading-order-562543ac12e9 (probably not the original source, i've seen the same thing on a zillion pages).

Comment: @KimmoLehto, I checked the tree, `.bashrc` is sourced: Interactive? = Yes → Login shell? = No → `--rc-file`? = No → `--norc`? = No → `/etc/bash.bashrc` → `~/.bash_rc`. Moreover, since you can define aliases (`alias` command) in your `.bashrc`, I would find it surprising.

Comment: It's not uncommon to source `.bashrc` from your `.bash_profile` because of that. 

1) Interactive? Yes 2) Login shell? Yes 3) `--noprofile`? No 4) `/etc/profile` 5) First of `~/.bash_profile`, `~/.bash_login`, `~/.profile` (***May*** *include `~/.bashrc`*  <= this I believe means that the file sourced may source `.bashrc` on its own).

The answer still does not match the diagram (no `.bash_login` or `~/.profile` and only load the first hit).

Remember, the idea is to emulate a login shell, not to replicate the non-login decision tree.